# The Bank Account Type dropdown does not work

Tags: authorize.net

On the Authorize.Net iframe (on an iPhone SE device, on Safari browser),
the dropdown does not expand when clicking on the "Bank Account Type" dropdown. Did anyone had this problem? How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Got it. And what is your question?

Comment: Thank you. It's very nice of you to notify us.